# $\sqrt{26}$ : Find by bisection method

Tags: metric-spaces

How would you find the root of $\sqrt{26}$ by bisection method?
A step by step solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Here it's quite step by step so check it out [Finding roots by binary search](http://www.mathpath.org/Algor/squareroot/algor.square.root.binary.htm)

Answer (score 4):

Let $f(x)=x^2$. 
$$
f(5) = 25 < 26\\
f(6) = 36 > 26\\
f(5.5) = 30.25 > 26\\
f(5.2) = 27.04 > 26\\
f(5.1) = 26.01 > 26\\
f(5.05) = 25.5025 < 26\\
f(5.07) = 25.7049 <26\\
f(5.09) = 25.9081 < 26\\
f(5.095) = 25.959025 < 26\\
f(5.098) = 25.989604 < 26\\
f(5.099) = 25.999801 < 26\\
f(5.0995) = 26.00490025 > 26\\
\dots
$$

Comment: note that $f(5.2)$ is not exactly bisection. A computer would use $f(5.25)$, $f(5.125)$ ...

Comment: But then the computer is working in binary (so it doesn't suffer working with more precision than is actually known) and computes with 2 bits of precision just as fast as 53 bits of precision anyways, so you can't really compare....